SQL Server PolyBase service fails to start
I'm running SQL Server 2022 Developer edition and want to use PolyBase to connect to some MongoDB database. However after installation I cannot seem to start the PolyBase Data Movement service.
It runs a few seconds, after which it stops.
When looking into the log files I see the following:
13/05/2024 14:52:53 \[Thread:7800\] \[GeneralInstrumentation:ThreadErrorEvent\] (Error, High):
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.SharedMemory.SmNative.SmCreateEx(Boolean xdeployMode, String sharedMemoryName, String ipcPrefixName, UInt32 buffersPerCQScan, UInt32 bufferSize, UInt32 regionCount, String nodeName, UInt32 nodeNameLength, Boolean useSecurityGroupForAcl, Boolean requireLocalMachineGroupForAcl, Boolean requireOrderedBuffers, IntPtr& sharedMemoryHandle)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.SharedMemory.NativeSharedMemory.Create(String sharedMemoryName, String ipcPrefixName, UInt32 buffersPerCQScan, UInt32 bufferSize, UInt32 regionCount, String nodeName, UInt32 nodeNameLength)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.CommandManager.DetachSqlServerAndCreateSharedMemory()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.CommandManager.ProcessInitConfigMessage(IMessage message)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.CommandManager.ProcessBaseMessage(IBaseMessage message)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.CommandManager.Run()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Common.ThreadManager.ThreadFactory.ExecuteCallback(Delegate callback, Object state, Boolean throwException, String name)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Common.ThreadManager.ThreadFactory.\<\>c__DisplayClass15_0.\<OnCreateThread\>b__0(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(Object obj)

In the Windows Event viewer I see the following:
The account 'PdwComputeNodeAccess' exists in a domain (MYDOMAINNAME) other than the local machine ().
Tried to reinstall SQL Server, The roles of the logins I_certSignPolyBaseAuthorize & I_certSignSmDetach are ok (sysadmin). TCP/IP is enabled

The account and the compute nodes must be in the same domain, see this article I wrote for reference: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/polybase-scale-out-group-in-azure-for-free
